# Unable to use inbuilt Visualisation in Zeppelin

Tags: cassandra, data-visualization, apache-zeppelin, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use the inbuilt visualization of **zeppelin** when retrieving data from **Cassandra keyspace** using s*park-cassandra connector*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql
val csc=new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val rdd1=csc.sql(“SELECT * from q_data.qr_ep_data limit 100”)
///rdd1.registerTempTable(“epdata”)
rdd1.registerTempTable(“epdata”)
%sql
SELECT * from q_data.qr_ep_data limit 10
Error::171: error: not found: value %
%sql
```

I am not able to use the `%sql` which throws me AN ERROR. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: %sql need be in the begin of a paragraph

Comment: %sql starts in the second paragraph only.